# Correct way to handle sample logins or test accounts

Tags: java

In my JSP web application, I want to redirect sample users to a different page from the real users.

Currently we do something like

```
if((user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Sample")) ...
```

This is (a) hardcoded and (b) executed for each normal user as well.

Is there a better way to handle this logic?

I am loathe to redirect these users via Javascript validation - which is one of the suggestions given internally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be better done through security groups.

Pseudo code:

```
if(user.InGroup("TestAccounts")).....
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem redirecting sample users like that. We are using this technic too so that we could use functional tests.

Another solution is writing a filter which you can then switch off.